# Memory Violation in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, pointer-to-pointer

I'm getting the following error when I run my code:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00F66754 in KSU.CIS308.Project5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFDFDFDFD.

I assume it is due to having memory for the pointer but not what it is pointing too. I have no clue how to assign it though. Here is the code, it is the constructor method for the Matrix objects:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int row, int col)
{
    this->rows = row;
    this->cols = col;
    this->arr = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        this->arr[i] = new int[col];
    }
}
```

The `this->arr = new int*[row];` is what is throwing it. It is a pointer to a pointer so that I can store the matrix like a 2-d array. Any help is much appreciated.
I think it is also being thrown later but if I can figure one out the rest should be easy to fix as well.

Arr is declared like this in the header file:

```
int **arr;
```

***Okay so when debugging I found that col is getting passed 0 which might explain the error.***
I thought I calculated the right value for passing it. Here is the main file. I use to strtok's to put everything into a Vector. User input format is: "1 2 3 // 3 2 1" Where "//" is row break.

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v1;
    int rowCountA = 1;
    int colCountA = 0;
cout << "Enter First Matrix (put // to denote row breaks): ";
    char buff[200];
    char *token;
    char *tok;
    scanf("%s", buff);
    token = strtok(buff, "//");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        tok = strtok(token, " ");
        while (tok != NULL)
        {
            v1.push_back(atoi(tok));
            tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
            colCountA++;
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, "//");
        rowCountA++;
    }



    A = new Matrix(rowCountA, colCountA/(rowCountA+1));

    for (int i = rowCountA; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int k = colCountA; k < 1; k--)
        {
            A->setElem(i, k, v1.back());
            v1.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need a matrix, consider a 1D array. A jagged 2D array is a big waste of performance.

Comment: How arr is declared?

Comment: I have to use a "int **arr". Which is part of the reason I cant figure it out as I have no experience using them.

Comment: -Dmitri Sosnik it is declared in the header file as int **arr;

Comment: This code *should* work to create your 2D array

Comment: The code you show [runs just fine](http://ideone.com/LEKF6O).

Comment: Could it have something to do with the possible values of row and column that are being passed in?

Comment: It could, but we couldn't say whether that is happening.  Can you edit your question to include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) ?

Answer (score 0):

As you've found out, the problem is passing 0 as one of the dimensions, the 2D-array creation is otherwise correct. You shouldn't ever allow `col` to be 0, worst case scenario (let's say empty input), make it be 1.

Anyway you aren't parsing the input correctly:

`scanf("%s")` is returning only the first number, because it [stops at the first space](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). Your code should use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead.

Using C string functions, you should replace your `scanf("%s", buff);` with:

```
fgets(buff, sizeof(buff)/sizeof(char), stdin);
```

But, you can't *nest* calls to `strtok()`. When you split the string on `//` and then call `strtok` on each token, you can no longer retrieve the next *row* because it forgets about the tokenizing based on `//`.

Here is a rough equivalent to the parsing you're doing using C++ i/o (although the code *does* have some other errors):

```
string sbuff;
getline(cin, sbuff);
stringstream ss(sbuff); // header file <sstream>
while (ss >> sbuff) {
    if (sbuff == "//") {
        rowCountA++;
    }
    v1.push_back(atoi(sbuff.c_str()));
    colCountA++;
}
```